# jQuery mobile - preserve list style after append

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

This question has been asked many times on stack overflow and I have tried all solutions from all the questions. Here is a list of them:

One:

```
var list = '';
for....
   list += 'html...';
$('#mylist').append(list);
$('#mylist').listview('refresh'); // appending all at once with var
```

Two:

```
for....
   $('#mylist').append('html...');
$('#mylist').listview('refresh'); // refresh once after appends
```

Three:

```
for....
   $('#mylist').append('html...');
$('#mylist').listview().listview('refresh'); // to init listview
```

Four:

```
for....
   $('#mylist').append('html...').listview('refresh'); // refresh after each append - BAD
```

There are more variations that I tried as well. Without the .listview('refresh') - the style is stripped on append. When I use the refresh call, it works but I get javascript error saying:

`**Uncaught Error: cannot call methods on listview prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'refresh'**

Using `.listview().listview('refresh')` does not work.

**SEE: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11943886/488407**

PS: I am using the latest version of jQuery mobile (v1.3.1) so this solution might have worked with earlier versions. I need to use the latest version as I am using Panels.

Comment: Wonderful essay. What is the question?

Comment: generally listview doesnt need a refresh event.. just be sure that you place this appending code in <body> whilst the refrerence to jQuery and jQM exist in the <head>

Comment: The question is - How do I preserve the style after adding items to the list.

Comment: @passionateCoder - I am doing this from a javascript closure in a bind function.

Comment: @JashSayani we need to see more code. Anyway Ive put in an answer. see if thats works out for you

Comment: `.listview('refresh')` should be added after appending all items. You're getting that error because you have placed it inside the loop.

Comment: @Omar - No, look at Two. I do one refresh after all appends.

Comment: Are you appending items to a panel?

Comment: @Omar - no Im using jQ mobile 1.3.1 because of panels. This is just a list on a page.

Comment: This is weird. Can u reproduce this issue on jsfiddle?

Comment: Yes - http://jsfiddle.net/u9TcE/

Comment: If you're using jQuery 2.0.2, then this is the problem. Stick to 1.9.1. Code is working normally http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/u9TcE/2/

Comment: @Omar - Its jQuery 1.9.1 and jQuery mobile 1.3.1

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/u9TcE/2/ no issues whatsoever.

Comment: @Omar - $('[data-role=listview]').listview('refresh') - gives the JS error mentioned in the question.

Comment: This is really weird. Are using ajax to load items? Where are you placing this code? Which event is used to load them `pageinit`, pagebeforecreate` etc...

Comment: @Omar - no AJAX. Its all in localStorage.

Comment: Ok, my second question was, when do you append them? On which event? Pageshow, pagehide, etc...

Comment: @Omar - I append when user choses "Add" and fills a form. Then I update localStorage and call the function again to clear the list and populate again from localStorage.

Comment: Pls post that block of code.

Answer (score 1):

## Approach 2 (most recent)

If you're absolutely sure you want to use `listview("refresh")`, I suggest you use `promise()` to resolve whether your `append` is completed or not and then apply the `refresh`. Like this :

```
var li = ""; //append to a string
for (var i = 0; i < accounts.length; i++) {
    li += '<li data-oid="' + accounts[i]._oid + '"><a><h2>' + accounts[i].nickname + ' - ' + accounts[i].bankname + '</h2><p>Balance: ' + accounts[i].acccy + " " + accounts[i].acbal + '</p></a></li>';
}

//check if append is done by chaining promise() and done() 
$('#accountlist').append(li).promise().done(function () {
    $(this).listview("refresh"); // refresh here
});
```

Demo here : http://jsfiddle.net/hungerpain/u9TcE/4/

More info here : [Promise Docs](http://api.jquery.com/promise/)

## Approach 1

**You need not to `refresh` listview**. `listview` elements dont need much css manipulation to make them look like how they look. So they are styled on the fly (ie, when you're `append`ing the `li` into a `ul` with `data-role` set to `listview`. Look at this array here :

```
var songs = [
             "Sweet Child 'O Mine", 
             "Summer of '69", 
             "Smoke in the Water", 
             "Enter Sandman", 
             "I thought I've seen everything"
            ];
```

Here's the HTML :

```
 <ul data-role="listview" id="songlist" data-theme="c" data-divider-theme="a" data-inset="true">
     <li data-role="list-divider" role="heading">Song List</li>
 </ul>
```

Here's how I'm going to inject this :

```
    $.each(songs, function (i, song) {
       $("<li/>", {
            "data-icon": "star",
            "class": "vote",
            "html": '<a href="#" id="song' + i + '">' + song + '</a>',
            "id": i
       }).appendTo("#songlist");
    });
```

**THATS IT**. You need not do anything more to get this work. The next thing which matters most is placement :

[image]

**Place your script in body and you're done.** The reason this works is because appending is synchronous in `<body>`. So you when this is used, you can be sure that the element is already loaded in DOM annd ready to be refreshed, which jQM automatically does.

[Here's a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hungerpain/TdHXL/5/)

**The options in jsFiddle - from jsFiddle [docs](http://doc.jsfiddle.net/basic/introduction.html)**

> **onLoad**: wrap the code so it will run in onLoad window event, place it in `<head>` section
>
> **onDomReady**: wrap the code so it will run in onDomReady window event, place it in `<head>` section
>
> **no wrap - in `<head>`**: do not wrap the JavaScript code, place it in `<head>` section
>
> **no wrap - in `<body>`**: do not wrap the JavaScript code, place it in `<body>` section

For your solution to work, copy the `<script>` tag in which you've written this/ the reference of the `js` file you've typed this in and paste it as the last element in `<body>`.

Comment: That is in a function called popualte() - things look good when its called upon init. The function is called again called after adds and then the style is lost.

Comment: @JashSayani pls put this in a fiddle @ http://jsfiddle.net and give us the URL :) Sorry im not able to see this clearly..

Comment: @JashSayani: http://jsfiddle.net/hungerpain/u9TcE/1/
I changed the placement of the script from `onLoad` to `no wrap in <body>` . this option is below the place where u choose the version of jquery

Comment: Hmm.. so it works without changing code. Can you update your answer explaining the difference between loading in "onLoad", "onDomReady", "No wrap - head", "No wrap - body". Would be good to understand this. Also, how do I fix this in my code?

Comment: @JashSayani i was using the timeout solution sometime back, but i found placing my scripts in `<body>` more performant and it involves less intervention.

Comment: Now I moved all script tags just before I close the body. Still same issue.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31817/discussion-between-passionatecoder-and-jash-sayani)

Comment: There must be something wrong in the code. I suspect that jQM events he's using is causing this. If adds a delay to refresh I assume it'd work with no issues. Like this issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17003064/jquerymobile-uncaught-exception-when-removing-checkboxradio/17009087#17009087

Answer (score -1):

Try `$("#your_list").trigger("refresh");`

```
for(...)
   $('#mylist').append('html...');

// call tirgger refresh after your append.
$("#your_list").trigger("refresh");
```